# How to stop cPanel messing with .htaccess and causing unexpected redirect

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

So I have many domains on one cPanel account, say `filmstore.net`, `bookstore.com` and `sandwiches.org` (the main domain).

So I want to redirect `anything.sandwiches.org` to `sandwiches.org`, so I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect subfolders (even with weird subdomains)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sandwiches\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^filmstore/(.*)$ https://www.filmstore.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sandwiches\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^bookstore/(.*)$ https://www.bookstore.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Otherwise, force www.sandwiches.org if it ends with sandwiches.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sandwiches\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sandwiches\.org(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sandwiches.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force www and SSL if naked
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL otherwise
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

So what does work? Well if I type for example `www.filmstore.sandwiches.org/bookstore/` I get redirected to `bookstore.com`, which is the expected behaviour.

However, I expect `www.filmstore.sandwiches.org` to go to `sandwiches.org`, which is what I've checked on the following website: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ - but this does not work. Instead, it sends me to `filmstore.net`, which I think is the default behaviour for multiple cPanel domains.

Also `cpanel.sandwiches.org` doesn't get redirected at all, nor something that doesn't exist like `blah.sandwiches.org`. Here it doesn't matter if I end with for example `/filmstore/`, it doesn't redirect.

My suspicion is that cPanel does something that takes over the `.htaccess` rules I have in my public_html. How can I solve this?

Running cPanel version 84.0.0.19

Comment: How are these additional domains created in cPanel? Are they "Addon" domains that point to subdomains of the _main domain_? If so, where do these subdomains point to? ...Subdirectories off the main domain's document root? Or somewhere else on the filesystem? Or are they domain "Aliases" that point to the main domain's document root? How are all these subdomains created? Do you have a "wildcard" subdomain configured (I assume not since you mention that some "don't exist")? Do you have other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Comment: In the filesystem everything is in public_html, which is the root for sandwiches.org. The other sites are in folders like /bookstore/ in public_html, the only way to have multiple domains on cPanel (at least with as much access as I have right now) is by going to "create addon domain". As for the .htaccess file I only have one big one in public_html. The .htaccess file does work for forcing www. or SSL when going straight to bookstore.com for example.

Comment: We would need to see the complete "big" `.htaccess` file in order to rule out conflicts. `"www.filmstore.sandwiches.org"` - Have you manually created the subdomain(s) `www.filmstore` (`www` and `filmstore`) of the `sandwiches.org` domain?

Comment: That is the big .htaccess file in the post, the subdomains were created automatically (when making an addon domain in cPanel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect `www.filmstore.sandwiches.org` to go to `sandwiches.org`, ...
>   This does not work, but sends me to `filmstore.net`, which I think is the default behaviour for multiple cPanel domains.

Ah, but the "problem" here is that the `www.filmstore` subdomain maps to the `/filmstore` subdirectory off the main domains document root (as stated in comments) - this mapping occurs before `.htaccess`. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* then matches against this *filesystem path*, which is caught by your first redirect directive:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sandwiches\.org$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^filmstore/(.*)$ https://www.filmstore.net/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

...and triggers the "undesirable" redirect to `filmstore.net`. Although this is arguably *correct* behaviour, ensuring both subdirectories *and* subdomains (associated with the Addon domain) are redirected to the correct domain. To override this and only redirect requests to the subdirectory and not the subdomain then you could add an additional condition that double-checks the requested URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?sandwiches\.org\.?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/filmstore/
RewriteRule ^filmstore/(.*) https://www.filmstore.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've tweaked the regex so that it only matches optional *subdomains*, as opposed to *anything* (which could potentially match other domains like `mysandwiches.org` etc.). And to allow for an optional trailing dot on the hostname (FQDN).

A request for the `filmstore` subdomain should not contain `/filmstore` in the URL-path (ie. `REQUEST_URI`), so should fall through to the canonical redirect for the `sandwiches.org` domain instead.

> Also `cpanel.sandwiches.org` doesn't get redirected at all

cPanel generally creates this subdomain as a shortcut to accessing the control panel interface itself. If you only have cPanel access then this is probably out of your control, as it completely bypasses your webspace (and `.htaccess` file).

> nor something that doesn't exist like `blah.sandwiches.org`

If a subdomain "doesn't exist" then it won't even resolve as there is no entry in DNS. (?) So any subdomain that "doesn't exist" won't even reach your server. (Unless you have configured "wildcard" subdomains? But then the subdomain arguably "does exist".)

Comment: I wanna add that I could fix it by adding more .htaccess files, such as in the /bookstore/ folder, but I want to keep it all in the main .htaccess file if it's possible, which I think it should be. I accept that blah.sandwiches.org won't redirect.

Comment: Ah, I think I've realised what is going on! I've _rewritten_ / updated my answer.